# How to place a small table of contents in the footer in ConTeXt?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, context, context-mkiv

I would like to place a small table of contents in the footer in ConTeXt, which only shows the sections within the current chapter, but it does not appear. This is what I tried:

```
\setupfootertexts[\setups{text c}][\setups{text c}][\setups{text c}][\setups{text c}]
\startsetups[text c]
    \midaligned{\placecontent[alternative=d, criterium=local]}
\stopsetups
\starttext
    \chapter{This is a chapter title}
        This is some text.
        \section{This is a section title}
            This is some more text.
        \section{This is another section title}
            This is yet some more text.
        \chapter{This is another chapter title}
            This is still some more text.
\stoptext
```

This results in an empty footer on all pages.

How can I place a table of contents list for the sections contained within the current chapter in the footer of my document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to put the table of contents in a box. Here I used the `framedtext`,
which puts the content in a `\vbox`. You can also use `\framed[align=normal]`.
Then I changed the `criterium` to `chapter` to only show the sections of the
current chapter. It's not clear if you want to list everything belonging to the current chapter or only the sections. Change the first argument to `\placelist` accordingly.

```
% Provides the fake words
\usemodule [visual]

\setupbodyfont [18pt]

\setupfootertexts [\setups{footertoc}] [\setups{footertoc}]

\startsetups [footertoc]
  \startframedtext [width=\textwidth, align=middle, frame=off]
    % remove subsection to only list the sections
    \placelist [section,subsection]
      [
        alternative=d,
          criterium=chapter,
             number=2,
      ]
  \stopframedtext
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startchapter [title=First Chapter]
  \startsection [title=Foo]
    \fakewords{30}{30}
  \stopsection
  \startsection [title=Bar]
    \fakewords{30}{30}
  \stopsection
  \startsection [title=Lorem]
    \fakewords{30}{30}
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\startchapter [title=Second Chapter]
  \startsection [title=Ipsum]
    \fakewords{30}{30}
  \stopsection
  \startsection [title=Dolor]
    \fakewords{30}{30}
  \stopsection
  \startsection [title=Sit]
    \fakewords{30}{30}
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

The result:

[image: result]

Comment: This code breaks as soon as there are deeper structure depths (e.g. subsections). To limit the list to sections only you need to request the level explicitly: `\placelist[section][alternative=d, criterium=chapter, number=2]`.

Comment: The code doesn't break, but it lists all content including subsections. What does `number` do?

Comment: `number` is needed to bypass the test in `strc-reg.lua`, line 150 because the default is zero. (Code seems to be alpha anyways.)

Answer (score 5):

With `\placelist[listname]` you can restrict the list placement. Then adjust the list content via the `number` and `criterium` keys:

```
\setupfootertexts [\setups{text c}] [\setups{text c}] 

\defineframed [footerframed] [
  align=middle,
  frame=off,
  height=\footerheight,
  width=\textwidth,
]

\startsetups [text c]
  \footerframed{%
    \placelist[section][  %% limit depth to section
      alternative=d,
      criterium=chapter,  %% local to chapter
      number=2,           %% request a structure depth
    ]
  }
\stopsetups
\starttext
\dorecurse{5}{
  \chapter{This is a chapter title}
    This is some text.
    \section{This is a section title}
      This is some more text.
    \section{This is another section title}
      This is yet some more text.
      \subsection{Deep Nesting}
        This is yet some more text.
      \subsection{doesn’t break}
        This is yet some more text.
      \subsection{the list!}
        This is yet some more text.
    \section{Yet another section title}
      This is yet some more text.
}
\stoptext
```

[image: table of contents in footer]